# Is there a fast way to delete a specific value from an array in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array

```
var array = ["google","chrome","os","windows","os"];
```

I want to delete the value `"chrome"` from the array without the array becoming a string. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: I find it hard to believe that someone named Chromedude would want to _delete_ Chrome from his array.

Comment: @ChessWhiz haha, did not even think of that, but it is in my array and it does need to be deleted :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no faster way than finding it and then removing it. Finding it you can do with a loop or (in implementations that support it) [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf). Removing it you can do with [`splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice).

Live example: http://jsbin.com/anuta3/2

```
var array, index;
array = ["google","chrome","os","windows","os"];
if (array.indexOf) {
  index = array.indexOf("chrome");
}
else {
  for (index = array.length - 1; index >= 0; --index) {
    if (array[index] === "chrome") {
      break;
    }
  }
}
if (index >= 0) {
  array.splice(index, 1);
}
```

Comment: Would that work in IE? I seem to recall seeing somewhere that it doesn't/didn't support `indexOf`?

Comment: Like TJ mentioned, not all browsers have indexOf implemented. You might need to implement your own.

Comment: @David: Not all implementations have it, hence the "with a loop" part of the answer. :-) Usually I just add `indexOf` to `Array.prototype` if it's not already there.

Comment: @DashK I am assuming its supported in firefox. Is that correct?

Comment: @chromedude: Yes (in fact, I linked to the MDC documentation for it in the answer)

Answer (score 3):

This wraps it up into a convenient function:

```
function remove_element(array, item) {
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; ++i) {
    if (array[i] === item) {
      array.splice(i, 1);
      return;
    }
  }
}

var array = ["google", "chrome", "os", "windows", "os"];
remove_element(array, "chrome");
```

or (for browsers that support `indexOf`):

```
function remove_element(array, item) {
  var index = array.indexOf(item);
  if (-1 !== index) {
    array.splice(index, 1);
  }
}
```

Edit: Fixed up with `===` and `!==`.

Comment: You should really be using `===` and `!==` instead of `==` and `!=`, respectively.

Comment: @Bears will eat you: No need for `!==` in `(-1 !== index)` ... index is known to be a number, because that's all indexOf will return, and -1 is known to be an number. So there's no need for strict comparison. I usually prefer something like `(index > -1)`; YMMV.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) method of the Array class.

```
array.splice(1, 1);
```

Answer (score 2):

The splice() method adds and/or removes elements to/from an array, and returns the removed element(s).

```
array.splice(indexOfElement,noOfItemsToBeRemoved);
```

in your case

```
   array.splice(1, 1);
```

Answer (score 2):

You may want to remove all of the items that match your string, or maybe remove items that pass or fail some test expression. `Array.prototype.filter`, or a substitute, is quick and versatile:

```
var array= ["google","chrome","os","windows","os"],
b= array.filter(function(itm){
    return 'os'!= itm
});
alert(b)
```

Answer (score 1):

You didn't mention whether its required to retain the indices of the remaining elements in your array or not. On the basis that you can deal with having `undefined` members of an array, you can do:

```
var array = ["google","chrome","os","windows","os"];
delete array[1];
```

`array[1]` will then be `undefined`.